# Remove the Duplicate Link

Tags: php, web-crawler

I wanna to crawl pdf links. But some links that I get are double. How to remove the one of the double links? Thank you :)

```
<?php
<include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=data+mining&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    $link= $e->href;
    if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $link)) {
       print_r($link);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the links in an array and then use array_unique()

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    $link= $e->href;
    if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $link)) {
       $links[] = $link;
    }
}
$links = array_unique( $links );
```

Comment: wow! thank you very much ! I don't know there's array_unique function. great ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=data+mining&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');
$arr = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    $link= $e->href;
    if(strtolower(substr($link, strrpos($link, '.'))) === '.pdf')
       $arr[] = $link;
}
array_unique($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

1. I'd recommend to use strings functions to get the the extension - it's lighter.
2. You can store your links in array, and then you use [array_unique()](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function.

Comment: wow, thanks for the advice ! I've tried it, and yes.. it gives faster execution time :)